# Complex Differentiation Question

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

[image]

Why is $\frac{∂v}{∂x}$= $\frac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$? Shouldn't it be $\frac{-2xy}{x^2+y^2}$

And shouldn't the $v$ be $\frac{-2xy}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: What is $1/z = 1/(x+iy)?$

Answer (score 1):

Since $v = \operatorname{Im}(f) = -\dfrac{y}{x^2+y^2}$, it is indeed true that $\dfrac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \dfrac{2xy}{x^2+y^2}$.

It looks like you (or the one who wrote the solution above) forgot about the minus sign in $v$.